# override map::compare with lambda function directly

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, lambda

Trying to override `map::compare` function using lambda, it seems that the following solution works.

```
auto cmp = [](const int&a, const int& b) { return a < b; };
std::map<int, int, decltype(cmp)> myMap(cmp);
```

But, I had to define `cmp` first and use it later.
Can I do this without defining 'cmp'?

Comment: `cmp` is not a function pointer.

Comment: Do _what_? `int`s already compare to each other. What are you trying to do? And why do you not want to use a function?

Comment: Yeah, function pointer was not an accurate term. Edited the question to make question more clear.

Comment: So what approach did you use that failed? We know you want something other than your example but not what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: But cannot captureless lambas be converted to a function pointer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, you **can't** use lambda in unevaluated context -- i.e. template parameters as in your example.
So you **must** define it somewhere else (using `auto`) and then use `decltype`... the other way, as it was mentioned already is to use an "ordinal" functors

If your question is about "**how to use lambda expression **once** when define a map**" you can exploit implicit conversion of lambdas to `std::function` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    auto m = std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(const int&, const int&)>>{
        [](const int& a, const int& b)
        {
            return a < b;
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

you may introduce an alias for that `map` type to reduce typing later...

Comment: However, using `std::function` would add a level of indirection and make it less efficient.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>

typedef std::map< int, int, std::function<bool(const int&, const int&)> > MyMap;

int main()
{
    auto cmp = [](const int& a, const int& b) { return a < b; };
    MyMap map(cmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Using `std::function` to provide the appropriate type signature for the comparator type you can define your map type and then assign any lambda compare you wish to.

Comment: This is what the OP is asking for, but really, introducing `std::function` feels like a bad solution. How about an alias template instead? `template<typename Comp> using MyMap = std::map<int, int, Comp>;` and then you don't have to define the comparator until you instantiate the map.

Comment: @Praetorian I'm stuck with an inferior compiler (VS2012) which doesn't support template aliases so I have no experience with them.

Comment: template aliases wouldn't help anyway: __you can't use lambda in unevaluated context__, but you have to specify a `Comp` parameter anyway (at instantiation point).

Comment: but you can use std::function<> in a template alias. see my post for example. I actually think std::function ins't a bad solution if there is a compelling reason to handle multiple maps with many different comparators especially if some capture a variable (in which case an arbitrary number of unique comparisons might exist).

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this where the type of the map is deduced from the function you pass to a function.

```
#include <map>

template<class Key, class Value, class F>
std::map<Key, Value, F> make_map(const F& f) {
    return std::map<Key, Value, F>{f};
}

int main() {
    auto my_map = make_map<int, int>([](const int&a, const int& b) { return a < b; });
    my_map[10] = 20;
}
```

I don't see a ton of reason for doing this but I wont say it's useless. Generally you want a known comparator so that the map can be passed around easily. With the setup above you are reduced to using template functions all the time like the following

```
tempalte<class F>
void do_somthing(const std::map<int, int, F>& m) {

}
```

This isn't necessarily bad but my instincts tell me that having a type which can ONLY be dealt with by generic functions is bad. I think it works out fine for lambda functions but that's about it. The solution here is to use std::function

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template<class Key, class Value>
using my_map_t = std::map<Key, Value, std::function<bool(const Key&, const Key&)>>;

int main() {
    my_map_t<int,  int> my_map{[](const int&a, const int& b) { return a < b; }};
    my_map[10] = 20;
}
```

Now you can use any predicate you want and you have a concrete type to work with, my_map

hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Since [C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> If no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted default
> constructor.

Thus you can do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/fE9Gjzvnv):

```
std::map<int, int, decltype([](const int&a, const int& b) { return a < b; })> myMap;


int main() {
    myMap.insert({7, 1});
    myMap.insert({46, 2});
    myMap.insert({56, 3});
    for (const auto& [key,value]:myMap) {
        std::cout <<  key <<  "  " << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```